# creating a list of column 'Name' from a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, sorting

When i use the code i've made it doesn't print the list for countries_all it prints []. countries is the countries with a positive net change.

```
import csv
import math


def main(file_name, region):
    
    
    min_country = None
    max_country = None
    min_population = math.inf
    max_population = -math.inf
    
    total_pop = 0
    total_countries = 0
    total_squared_diff = 0
    num_countries = 0
    
    density_pop = {}
    
    countries_all = []

    
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        countries = [row for row in csv.DictReader(file) if row['Regions'] == region and float(row['Net Change']) > 0]    #Reads the CSV file and finds a list of countries in a specific region with positive net change in population
        inline = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in file:
            columns = row.strip().split(',')
            countries_all = columns[0]
            
        print(countries_all)
```

This is the file that I am rereferring to. I am expecting it to store and print the names of the countries in the column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating an inline reader, it's better to read the individual lines from the file. This should fix it:

```py
    lines = file.readlines()
    for row in lines:
        columns = row.strip().split(',')
        countries_all = columns[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way :

```
import csv
​
with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=",")
    
    countries_all = [row["Name"] for row in reader if int(row["Net Change"]) > 0]
```

Output:

```
print(countries_all)
​
 ['Armenia', 'Qatar', 'Bahrain', 'Timor-Leste', 'Bhutan', 'Macao', 'Maldives', 'Brunei',
  'Western Sa', 'Cabo Verde', 'Mayotte', 'Sao Tome &', 'Seychelles', 'Malta', 'Iceland',
  'Channel Isla', 'Isle of Man', 'Andorra', 'Faeroe Islar', 'Monaco', 'Liechtenste',
  'San Marinc', 'Holy See', 'Antigua an', 'Dominica', 'Cayman Isla', 'Saint Kitts i',
  'Sint Maarte', 'Turks and (', 'Saint Marti', 'British Virg', 'Caribbean I', 
  'Anguilla', 'Montserrat', 'Falkland Isl', 'United Stat', 'Canada', 'Greenland',
  'Nauru', 'Niue', 'Tokelau']
```